# How to solve the "Error Mounting..." error dialog in LXDE / PCManFM

Tags: mount, lxde, pcmanfm

I'm getting the following dialog from time to time when playing music from my external HD (Seagate Expansion+ 2TB):

[image]

Whenever that happens, my music player (cmus) skips to the next track. 
This happens with any music player I use, it doesn't happen all the time though.

If not solving the issue, I'd like to no longer get these dialog popups, as they come in groups of 3-4, and often cannot be closed at all.

**Update**

I'd like to also note that my Seagate Hard Drive is connected through an i-tec USB 3.0 Docking Station, in case it's relevant.